# Allow port forwarding through vpn iptables killswitch

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, openvpn, port-forwarding

I have a debian virtual machine thats connect to a openvpn server. Right now i have a kill switch working well on iptable, and the vpn connection works whithout any trouble. Let's share this configuration right now:

```
*filter

:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ens -s 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -i tun0 -s 111.11.11.10 --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o -lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o ens -d 111.11.11.10 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o ens -d 24.24.24.16/24 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o ens -d 255.255.255.255 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

But now I'm trying to forward a service running on a virtual machine on my network. I need to give access from a specific port on the vpn server. And i tried really all tutorials on the web but i should misunderstanding something or doing something wrong, this is why i call for help.

```
VPN Interface tun0:
Public ip 111.11.11.10
Public port to forward 1234

Private network ens:
Debian vm ip 24.24.24.16 (so the vm where iptables and the vpn is running)
Destination vm ip 24.24.24.48 (the vm who need to be forwarded through the vpn)
Destination vm port 6789
```

This is what i tried

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 24.24.24.48:6789
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 24.24.24.48 --dport 6789 -j ACCEPT
route add -net 24.24.24.0/24 dev tun0
```

When i use `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`, this is what i get
https://i.stack.imgur.com/65rQF.png

So the packets len incoming from the external port increase, this mean the prerouting should be good but i'm unable to reach the destination VM from the vpn. Can yu explain me what i'm missing

Comment: on which machine did you execute the DNAT rule? it looks like you did that on your debian VM, but since you are using the public IP of your openvpn server, that is the place where the DNAT rule belongs to...

Comment: I'm running this DNAT rule on the Debian VM yes. So the VPN provider is outside my network, i really don't understand what your trying to say. 
Debian play as firewall and openvpn client. I know the external port is reserved by the vpn server and traffic should be allowed. What yu think ?

Comment: I wrote an answer to clarify things... hope it helps

Comment: Why did you add route for 24.24.24.0/24 (that uses `tun0` as the route interface)? Is `24.24.24.16` the default gateway on `24.24.24.48`?

Answer (score 0):

I need to make some assumptions to answer your question, but you are missing a critical point here. You can only modify connections with a DNAT rule which arrive at your server:

```
_______________       priv.   ___________   private        __________
| VPN server   |      subnet A|          |  subnet B       | dest. VM
| 111.11.11.10 |----------tun0| debian VM|ens--------------|
|--------------|              |----------|   24.24.24.0/24 |---------
```

I am assuming here that the subnet used by the tun0 interface is a private IP space, and is NOT holding the public IP directly. You want to publish the port 1234 of your destination VM to the internet.

You redirect all traffic through your VPN, making sure you are not able to access the internet without VPN connection. This means the IP visible to the rest of the internet is the public IP of your VPN provider, 111.11.11.10 .

Now, Lets suppose I want to access the service on port 1234 you are publishing. The connection will go to your VPN provider - and the server must know what to do with that incoming connection, otherwise it will simply drop it. That is the reason you need to place the DNAT rule at your openvpn server... If that server is out of your control, you are out of luck.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer, i really appreciate the time you allow to me. So just to be hundred purcent sure we talk about the same thing, the public IP and port i used are reserved, this means, if i use a simple windows VM with openvpn and default port forward, everything works great.
What i don't unserstand, is why i wouldn't be able to reach the destination VM, considering the forwarding debian VM is able to access to the destination.

Comment: To be more clear, i have a web interface on the same subnetwork as the debian forwarding VM have. If i have access to the interface on debian on the subnet, why wouldn't be able to forward the public port to the local ip/port, expecting the same behaviour as a local port forwarding on the same VM. Is it what you try to explain to me ? So if i use the same forward VM that host the same external port, i would be able to do it ? Trying to forward an external port to an another local subnetwork vm is not possible ?

Comment: of course you can forward the port on your debian VM. The problem I am referring to is that you are only able to publish the port to what I have called "private subnet A" - the internal network of your VPN connection. Doing so does NOT publish the port to the public internet!